# HTML5 animation without using spritesheet

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, animation

I'm using Phonegap to build a simple app, I wonder if there is any solution to make an animation not using a spritesheet, the only [example](http://codepen.io/rachelnabors/pen/AeEHw) I've found so far is using different divs, which is not too good if we consider it's performance. I want something like:

```
Animation anim = new Animation();
anim.add("move1.png");
anim.add("move2.png");
anim.add("move3.png");
anim.add("move4.png");
anim.start();
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I might not be too familiar, but can you use an animated gif for each animation?

Answer (score 2):

why not using simple javascript interval?

## HTML

```
<img id="animate" src="#"/>
```

## Javascript

```
var images = ["img1",
              "img2",
              "img3",
              "img4"],
    i = 0;


$animate = $("#animate");
$animate.attr( "src" , images[i] );
setInterval(function(){
    i = ( i === (images.length - 1) ) ? 0 : i + 1;
    $animate.attr("src",images[i]);
}, 1000);
```

you can see that's working: http://jsfiddle.net/ugn7fn79/2/

if i didnt understood you please tell me and ill try to improve my answer.

Comment: Yeah it's cool, but is it effective if we consider it's performance? I mean the **$animate.attr("src",images[i]);** part, not the **setInterval** which is said to bee slow and as far as I know I should use **requestNaimation** instead.

Comment: in fact * window.requestAnimation * is exactly for your needs, but not really [full-supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame#Browser_compatibility) multi-browsers. its on your on hands.